# Why does $(document).ready(function () { $("body").prepend('<p>I\'m a paragraph!</p>');});

Tags: jquery

Why does this only work for "body"? I tried it with head and id tags but it doesn't work once I change it to them. And even so, it works only in a blank html but not in this file.

text to fit posting quota.text to fit posting quota.text to fit posting quota.text to fit posting quota.text to fit posting quota.text to fit posting quota.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>

    <style>
    body{font-size:30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "sans-serif";}

    table {
        margin-top:50px;
        background-color:white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        width:50%
    }

    td {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .spanrows1,
    .spanrows2 {
         text-align: center;
    }  

    .spanrows1 {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .spanrows2 {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .span2rows {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .squareDivs {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#000000;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .squareTxt {
        line-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;    
    }

    .alignTxt{text-align: center;}

    </style>
    </head>

    <body> 

        <div class="alignTxt"><span id="titleTxt"></span></div>

    <table>
    <tr>
         <td class='spanrows2'>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
            <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you mean changing `body` to other elements (e.g. `#myid`)?

Comment: `head` cannot contain any outputtable content. `id` tags don't exist in HTML.

Comment: The ID tag certainly has been set in my HTML. @Arefly Yes, though, I'm unfamiliar with your method. I'm trying to add things to HTMlL purely through .JS file.

Comment: @shoryuu it would be better if you could edit your question and add both HTML and JS code you've tried.

Comment: I've just done so. My JS file consists of nothing more but $(document).ready(function () { $(“body”).prepend('<p>I\'m a paragraph!</p>');});

Answer (score 0):

Because head tag only contain there tags

```
<title> 
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```

if you append other tag it's prepended to body